# Image processing from the client through TCP socket failed

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, tcp

I am developing an application for viewing client screen over TCP socket. my server application is in C# and the client application is in C++. I could send the image to the server without any error.  At the server end, while converting buffer length I am getting a big number and this causes 'Overflow exception' while making image buffer with that size. Following are the code I have tried.

Server Code

==========

```
public static void StartListening()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
    // The DNS name of the computer
    // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 11000);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadHeaderCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadHeaderCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    //we need to add error handler here...but later
    state.ImageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
    _imageBuff = new byte[state.ImageSize];
    _totBytesRead = 0;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
       new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);


    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(state.buffer, 0, _imageBuff, _totBytesRead, bytesRead);

        _totBytesRead += bytesRead;

        if (_totBytesRead < state.ImageSize)
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\incoming\untitled.bmp", _imageBuff);
        }
    }
}
public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
```

## Client Code

```
void SendScreen()
{
HDC hdcScreen;
HDC hdcWindow;
HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
BITMAP bmpScreen;

HWND hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();

// Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
// area of the window. 
hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

// Create a compatible DC which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC
hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow); 

if(!hdcMemDC)
{
    //MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleDC has failed",L"Failed", MB_OK);
    goto done;
}

// Get the client area for size calculation
RECT rcClient;
GetClientRect(hWnd,&rcClient);

//This is the best stretch mode
SetStretchBltMode(hdcWindow,HALFTONE);

//The source DC is the entire screen and the destination DC is the current 
window (HWND)
if(!StretchBlt(hdcWindow, 
           0,0, 
           rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, 
           hdcScreen, 
           0,0,
           GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN),
           GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN),
           SRCCOPY))
    {
    MessageBox(hWnd, "StretchBlt has failed","Failed", MB_OK);
    goto done;
}

// Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC
hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right-rcClient.left, 
rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top);

if(!hbmScreen)
{
    MessageBox(hWnd, "CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed","Failed", MB_OK);
    goto done;
}

// Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
SelectObject(hdcMemDC,hbmScreen);

// Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
if(!BitBlt(hdcMemDC, 
           0,0, 
           rcClient.right-rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top, 
           hdcWindow, 
           0,0,
           SRCCOPY))
   {
    MessageBox(hWnd, "BitBlt has failed", "Failed", MB_OK);
    goto done;
   }

// Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP
GetObject(hbmScreen,sizeof(BITMAP),&bmpScreen);

BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;    
BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    
bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;    
bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;  
bi.biPlanes = 1;    
bi.biBitCount = 32;    
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
bi.biClrImportant = 0;

DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth  bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32)  4 * 
bmpScreen.bmHeight;
HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND,dwBmpSize); 
char lpbitmap = (char )GlobalLock(hDIB);    
GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0,
    (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
    lpbitmap,
    (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("capture.bmp",
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);   

// Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size
DWORD dwSizeofDIB = dwBmpSize + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

//Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 

//Size of the file
bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB; 

//bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps
bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; //BM    


DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
SendingToSocketBFH(bmfHeader);
SendingToSocketBIH(bi);
SendingToSocket(lpbitmap,dwBmpSize);


//Unlock and Free the DIB from the heap
GlobalUnlock(hDIB);    
GlobalFree(hDIB);

//Close the handle for the file that was created
CloseHandle(hFile);

//Clean up
done:
DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL,hdcScreen);
ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdcWindow);
}

void SendingToSocketBFH(BITMAPFILEHEADER bfinfo)
{
DWORD dwErr=0;
int sent=0;
sent = Send((char*)&bfinfo,sizeof(bfinfo),0);
dwErr = GetLastError();
}

void SendingToSocketBIH(BITMAPINFOHEADER binfo)
{
DWORD dwErr=0;
int sent=0;
sent = Send((char*)&binfo,sizeof(binfo),0);
dwErr = GetLastError();
}

void SendingToSocket(char* cpBuff,int iLen)
{
DWORD dwErr=0;
int sent=0;
sent = Send(cpBuff,iLen,0);
dwErr = GetLastError();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the send method send do two sends 1) (pseudo code ) Send((char*)sizeof(binfo), 8 ,0); 2) Send((char*)&binfo,sizeof(binfo),0);  The code will send 8 bytes at beginnning of data which contains the lenght of the data to follow.  Then in c# code extract length and then change following line of code : if (bytesRead > 0).  TCP you can get datagrams with zero length in middle of a message.

Comment: I have done the thing and I got the above snapshot value on the receiver end. Seems to be a negative value for state.ImageSize. hence this  'if (_totBytesRead < state.ImageSize)' fails at the very first time. and it go for writing the image.

Comment: At first glance, your code appears to assume that your two sends will result in your C# code needing to do 2 receives. That is not how TCP works, it gives you a byte stream only, and there are no guarantees that the number of writes at one end will need the same amount of reads on the other end. Please ensure you know at all times how much data you have received on your cllient, and that you don't throw away data because you think you only received the first 8 bytes, but in reality you received the first 8 bytes and the first half of the image.

Comment: You likely also need to reverse the bytes for the length field before using BitConverter, you probably send the length in little endian format, but convert the length bytes with BitConverter, assuming it is big endian format.

Comment: My psuedo code was sending 8 bytes, your code is reading int32 instead of a long which may be reason you are getting negative number.  Should be able to get size using : byte[] b = { 52, 48, 0, 253, 253, 253, 253, 171 };
            ulong size = BitConverter.ToUInt64(b,0);

Comment: The expression for initializing `dwBmpSize` is missing some operators. `char lpbitmap = (char )GlobalLock(hDIB);` may be missing some `*`s.

Comment: @jdweng we tried with your suggestion " Send((char*)sizeof(binfo), 8 ,0); " in our client application, but the Send function fails and returns error code 10014 (The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call). Kindly advice.

Comment: I t was only meant to be pseudo code.  You need to put the sizeof(bin) (An integer) into a byte array of 8 characters.

Comment: In c++ we can't directly send the length through the socket. So we just used the following code to send the size of the image.
CString csLen="";
csLen.Format("%d",iLen);
sent=Send((char*)csLen.GetBuffer(),8,0);
But on the reciever end we get huge value for the image size.

Comment: @jdweng is there any other way to pass image between C++ client and C# server socket??

Comment: If client and server are on same PC then you can use a stream class like standard input and standard output.